# please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I apologize in advance if this is awful code. It is the first real thing I have tried to do completely unassisted. I am trying to get it to read the first 4 lines from a file.

```
from sys import argv 

script, filename = argv

print "Is %r the file you wish to open?" % filename
print "If you do not wish to continue type CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do wish to continue, please hit RETURN."

raw_input("Are you sure?")

print "Opening %r please wait... " % filename
target = open(filename, 'r')

print "Thank you for you request."

print "The file contains the lyrics to a certain song, can you guess it?"
target.read("line 1: ")
target.read("\n")
target.read("line 2: ")
target.read("\n")
target.read("line 3: ")
target.read("\n")
target.read("line 4: ")
target.read("\n")

song = raw_input("Go on, take a guess!")

print "%r? Good Guess!" % song

print "Goodbye!"
target.close()
```

Comment: Why do you think the code is wrong? Do you get errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the middle block of your code to:

```
print "Opening %r please wait... " % filename
print "Thank you for you request."

print "The file contains the lyrics to a certain song, can you guess it?"
with open(filename, 'r') as target:
    for lineNum in range(4):
        print target.readline()
```

If you were intending to print the line number preceding the line, you could do something like

```
with open(filename, 'r') as target:
    for lineNum in range(1,5):
        print 'line {}: '.format(lineNum) + target.readline()
```

Comment: Actually `read` can take an integer as an argument to set how many bytes to read.

Comment: "not sure what you're expecting when you pass `line 4`". I bet he expected it to work the same way `raw_input` does: print the first argument, then receive data from some input channel.

Answer (score 0):

use `target.readline()` the "line 1:" and is garbage. also the new line is read by default and you dont need to read it!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) returns a [file object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects). File objects have a [`read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) method taking an optional `size` parameter to read a certain amount of bytes:

> `file.read([size])`
>   Read at most `size` bytes from the file (less if the
>   read hits EOF before obtaining `size` bytes). If the `size` argument is
>   negative or omitted, read all data until `EOF` is reached. The bytes are
>   returned as a string object. An empty string is returned when `EOF` is
>   encountered immediately. (For certain files, like ttys, it makes sense
>   to continue reading after an `EOF` is hit.) Note that this method may
>   call the underlying C function `fread()` more than once in an effort to
>   acquire as close to `size` bytes as possible. Also note that when in
>   non-blocking mode, less data than was requested may be returned, even
>   if no `size` parameter was given.

You are passing `size="line 1: "`.